# Eclipse plugin (reinstall ?)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, eclipse-3.6, helios

I'm working for a long time with Eclipse Helios 3.6 and have a lot of plugins installed from the Eclipse webpage. Now, I wanted switch to the Eclipse Version Juno 4.2

My question: Can I use the old plugins from my Helios or must I reinstall the plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure, but Eclipse should be backwards compatible. Just add the update site for Eclipse 4.2, run the upgrade and the plugins should continue to work. Sometimes features (that are possibly used by the plugins) are marked as deprecated, but I think they are not removed from Eclipse.

Other than that: You could make a backup (or a simple copy) and try it out to be sure.